# Redrawing a line from two points gives slightly inaccurate results

Tags: c++, opencv, math

Recently I started working on a project with OpenCV and C++.
I graph a curved line on desmos, and feed it into the program. The objective of the program is to measure how curved the line is, and how much to straighten it.

The red line you see in the image below (with the green and red dots on it) is the graphed line from desmos. The purple line with hollow circles on it is the model line that needs to be met. I have written some basic functions to calculate what each x value of a given y value would be on the straight line. I did this in order to align the points from the curved line with points on the straight line.

[image: In correct slope calculation]

The code for calculating the values is:

```
double slopeOf(Point first, Point second) {
    return (second.y - first.y) / (second.x - first.x);
}

double f(Point first, Point second, int y) {
    // return x of point with y value, on given line
    return ((y - first.y) / slopeOf(first, second)) + first.x;
}
```

As you can see, the hollow points at the bottom of the line are centered with the straight line, and they are accurate. But the higher up you go in the line, the points begin to stray away from the line.

Why is this happening?

Also: I tired using the LineIterator in OpenCV but couldn't get the flexible results I would if I used my own functions.

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Comment: What type are the components of `Point`? If those are `double`s, why are you using `int` for `y`?

Comment: OpenCV only uses integers for point coordinates. Would your deviation come from this (maybe amplified with the fact that your computation using the slope is effectively a first-order integration) ?

Comment: @Bob__ OpenCV uses Ints for points. I switched the functions types to doubles, in the hopes that it would increase the accuracy.

Comment: @Ben That's what I thought as well. But then how would I fix this issue? I'm not that good at math, but i'm looking into first-order integration.

Comment: I am not sure if you already changed the type of the points. Instead of using `cv::Point` you could use `cv::Point2f` or `cv::Point2d`. I think this is also what @Ben meant.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. First-order integration is basically doing y(t) = y(0) + t*dy/dt. That's what you do, and it's OK for straight lines. The problem is that if your dy/dt (here your slope) has a slight error, you amplify it. For example if you have an estimate which is (dy/dt + e), for t = 2  your error is 2*e and for t=10 your error is 10*e. You can increase the accuracy of computations first by using float instead of ints, and second by taking points far from each other (i.e. two ends of the line) to compute the slope.